# After Civil War, which Spider-Man storylines are required to catch up to Last Remains?

Tags: marvel, comics, suggested-order, spider-man

I have read the events of Civil War, and I have the Spider-Man comics for Ends of the Earth which I've also read through.

I've recently learnt about Morlun, who appears in later comics, the last of which seems to be *Last Remains*. That storyline seems to tie back into *One More Day*, whose story started in *Back In Black*, based on this wikipedia paragraph:

> The 2020 storyline Last Remains and it's subsequent fallout furthered the One More Day connections in the storylines,

> as the mysterious demon, aka Kindred, shows his hand and uses his powers to revive the Sin Eater and possess several of Spider-Man's allies, turning them against him and all of New York City. Peter goes to Doctor Strange for assistance, but Strange discovers something is wrong with Peter's soul.

The fact that *Back in Black* starts directly after *Civil War* conveniently means I shouldn't need to go any further back.

Which of the Trade Paperbacks (my prefered method of collecting comics) are required to fill this fill this 13 year gap? It looks like a few of the [storylines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Spider-Man_storylines) (which I can use to look up the TBPs) are inconsequential? Things like *New Ways to Die* and *Spidey Meets the President!*. Are they? Are any others skippable filler?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to prepare for Last Remains. then I think that it's safe to skip everything through [Go Down Swinging](https://www.marvel.com/videos/amazing-spider-man-go-down-swinging-teaser-trailer) which concludes Dan Slott's run on Amazing Spider-Man. The series was relaunched with [Marvel NOW!](https://www.marvel.com/comics/events/311/marvel_now) in [Parker Luck](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/45799/amazing_spider-man_vol_1_parker_luck_trade_paperback).

[How to Love Comics](https://www.howtolovecomics.com/2020/10/11/amazing-spider-man-last-remains-reading-order/) has a Background Reading List for Last Remains. It basically recommends reading Nick Spencer's run on the series, starting with [Back to Basics](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/67632/amazing_spider-man_by_nick_spencer_vol_1_back_to_basics_trade_paperback) and then [Friends and Foes](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/67634/amazing_spider-man_by_nick_spencer_vol_2_friends_and_foes_trade_paperback).

There is a [Sins Rising Prelude](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/30597/amazing_spider-man_sins_rising_prelude_2020_-_present) series, but I have not actually read either it or Last Remains.

If you're specifically interested in Morlun, his first appearance was in [The Other](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/5187/spider-man_the_other_trade_paperback). That story was not originally part of the main continuity, but was retconned to be included. Morlun is only one of the Inheritors, who are the main villains of [Spider-Verse](https://www.marvel.com/comics/events/321/spider-verse).

Comment: This is a promising start. Are none of the other intervening story lines relevant at all? Or are you suggesting I look at the Spider-Verse suggested background reading, and Sins Rising as well as the list for last remains on How To Love Comics?